# Really strange behaviour in VS, I can build with a bad use of ForEach

Tags: c#, .net, linq, compilation, visual-studio-2022

I have the following code:

```
    var myCollection = myOriginalCollection.Select(e => _mapper.Map<MyType>(e.Item2));
    myCollection.ForEach(myObject => myObject.myProp = myValue);
```

This compiles, and it fact it runs - I've been testing it and it doesn't `throw`.

2 things are very weird here:

- I shouldn't be able to call `ForEach` on an `IEnumerable<T>`, and I can confirm `myCollection` is definitely an `IEnumerable<T>`
- The strangest thing - if I add `ToList` to the first line (so that `myCollection` is `List<T>` instead of `IEnumerable<T>`), and *then* I remove that `ToList`, suddenly my code won't compile i.e. I *can't* call `ForEach` on my `IEnumerable<T>` anymore, which is expected.

Is this some bug in VS/the compiler? I've never seen anything like this before

Comment: what happens when you clean and rebuild?

Comment: @AbdelkrimBournane - good question, let me try... EDIT: Still builds

Comment: Maybe you have an extension `ForEach` on `IEnumerable<T>`

Comment: You added `ToList` and then removed it, and it now doesn't compile as expected. So how do you go back to the state where it worked? If you can't reproduce the behaviour, then it was probably just the IDE running an old version.

Comment: @TimSchmelter - good point, we don't - but it's a great suggestion

Comment: @TimSchmelter - you cracked it, posting an answer now...

Answer (score 2):

I believe this a case of, what they call, PEBCAK ('problem exists between computer and keyboard').

We're (apparently) using a library called `ParseLibrary.Utilities` which has an extension for `IEnumerable<T>`!

Why adding `ToList()` to this (and then removing it) breaks it is because I have VS configured to remove unused namespaces on save. So, when I add `ToList`, the `ForEach` is no longer from that lib, so it strips out the `using ParseLibrary.Utilities` when I hit save.

Comment: _"So, when I add ToList, the ForEach is no longer from that lib (it's probably from System.Linq or something)"_ No, that's the old [`ForEach`-method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.foreach?view=net-7.0) in `List<T>`. Good to have the `ForEach` extension, you should put it into your own library to reduce dependencies for common methods.

Comment: Updated - thanks for your help! It was a real head-scratcher this one, I really appreciate you nudging me towards looking more into the extension I was calling.

Comment: @TimSchmelter - so what I'm investigating here (which led to this) was that the value of `myProp` is not being set! Maybe you can help me understand why? But my suspicions are this extension is not operating on the same objects in memory that I then pass to a method which requires that prop to be set. I'm going to call `ToList` and try that anyway.

Comment: @JayMee: maybe `MyType` is a value type like `struct`, so you get copies